# Integrating MATLAB with Google BigQuery via REST API

Tags: matlab, rest, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use MATLAB's webread function to query Google BigQuery via the REST API, and am having issues. The following curl request is successful:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<MyProjectId>/queries' \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <MyBearerToken>' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"query":"select count(1) from MyTable","useLegacySql":false}' \
  --compressed
```

However, the following MATLAB code:

```
api = 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/';
access_token = '<MyAccessToken>';
options = weboptions('RequestMethod', 'post');
r = webread([api 'projects/<MyProjectId>/queries?access_token=' access_token], ...
    'query', 'select count(1) from MyTable', ...
    'useLegacySql', false, ...
    options);
```

generates the following error:

```
Error using readContentFromWebService (line 45)
The server returned the status 400 with message "Bad Request" in response to the request to URL
https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<MyProjectId>/queries?access_token=<MyAccessToken>&query=select+count(1)+from+<MyTable>&useLegacySql=0
```

Entering the URL in the MATLAB error into a POST requester shows the following (generic) error, so it appears the URL is malformed:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Required parameter is missing"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Required parameter is missing"
    }
}
```

How can I use MATLAB's webread to accomplish the same thing as the above curl request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `webread` function doesn't have this functionality. This issue is resolved successfully by using `webwrite` as follows:

```
options = weboptions( ...
    'RequestMethod', 'post', ...
    'MediaType', 'application/json');
data = struct( ...
    'query', 'select count(1) from MyTable', ...
    'useLegacySql', false);
r = webwrite([api 'projects/<MyProjectId>/queries?access_token=' access_token], ...
    data, ...
    options);
```